# Problems about Vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that the set $V = \{p(x):p(x)$ ***is a polynomial with real coefficients and*** $p(3)=0\}$ is a vector space.

The p(3)=0 is throwing me off. To show V is closed under vector addition, I would show that for some polynomial f(x) and g(x) f(x)+g(x) would have to be closed under vector addition but how would p(3)=0 fit into f(x)+g(x).

Comment: what is $f(3)+g(3)$ if $f(3)=g(3)=0$?

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you, feel dumb now.

Comment: no need. everybody has such moments.

Answer (score 0):

We already know that the set of all polynomials is a vector space, so all you have to do is to prove that $V$ is a vector subspace of it using vector subspaces criterion, i.e, $0\in V$ and $\forall P,Q\in V,\forall a,b\in\mathbb{F},\, P+(-Q)\in V$ where $\mathbb{F}$ is the field where we're working (generally $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$). The way you prove the last thing is similar to how you can show what you're asking for: closure under $+$, i.e:$$\forall P,Q\in V,\,P+Q\in V$$

So let $P,Q\in V$ (they are arbitrary choosen which fits with $\forall P,Q\in V$). Thus $P(3)=Q(3)=0$.

Now, since $V$ equals the set of polynomials for which 3 is a root, we have:$$P+Q\in V\Leftrightarrow(P+Q)(3)=0$$

But we know that $(P+Q)(X)=P(X)+Q(X)$ so in particular $(P+Q)(3)=P(3)+Q(3)$. What can you say?